# Split data into 3 ordered chunks of as-close-to equal size as possible

Tags: r

I would like to split this into three chunks whose size is as equal as possible, in such a way that earlier chunks have more entries than later chunks if equality is *not* possible.

Say I have something like:

`x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 , 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)`

I'd like:

```
[1]
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

[2]
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13

[3]
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
```

I can achieve this by defining my own function, using the length of `x` modulo 3, and the floor of the length of `x` divided by 3 to determine the size of each chunk, but is there some way to achieve this in `split` or some such thing that's already defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `seq_along` to generate a vector of indices and use module division to divide it into three chunks, sort the indices and split on the sorted indices give the expected result:

```
split(x, sort((seq_along(x) - 1)%%3))  # -1 here to convert it to zero based indices so that 
                                       # extra elements will always stack from earlier chunks

# $`0`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

# $`1`
# [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13

# $`2`
# [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Answer (score 1):

We divide the `length` of 'x' by 3 and `split` it after replicating the sequence of 3 with `ceiling` and `round` of 'i1'.

```
i1 <- length(x)/3
split(x, rep(1:3, c(ceiling(i1), round(i1), floor(i1))))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

#$`2`
#[1]  8  9 10 11 12 13

#$`3`
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19
```